# Create card token in Stripe via Java

Tags: java, token, stripe-payments

I want to use the Stripe.com on the server-side. When I try to create card token via

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/tokens \
   -u sk_test_qMabFX3j5ApELqUH8mEy6NDp: \
   -d card[number]=4242424242424242 \
   -d card[exp_month]=12 \
   -d card[exp_year]=2019 \
   -d card[cvc]=123
```

or via

```
Stripe.apiKey = "sk_test_qMabFX3j5ApELqUH8mEy6NDp";

Map<String, Object> tokenParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();
Map<String, Object> cardParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();
cardParams.put("number", "4242424242424242");
cardParams.put("exp_month", 6);
cardParams.put("exp_year", 2019);
cardParams.put("cvc", "314");
tokenParams.put("card", cardParams);

Token.create(tokenParams);
```

I see the message in my dashboard:
"We saw *nnn* requests in the last *m* days with raw credit card numbers"

My questions are:
1) Can I safely use the Java API to create a card token? If yes, how to avoid such messages?
2) Or I have to use Stripe elements and one of their scripts for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create card tokens server-side in Java, this means that your servers received raw card details. Even if you don't save the information in your database, you still fall under a higher level of PCI compliance which would be a lot of work to comply with.

Instead, you should tokenize client-side, using [Elements](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js#elements) or [Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout). This would let you create a card token securely client-side and then send that token to your server. This would also let you fall under SAQ-A which is the easiest level for PCI compliance. You can read more about the differences in Stripe's docs [here](https://stripe.com/docs/security#validating-pci-compliance).

Answer (score 1):

**QUESTION 1**:

Can I safely use the Java API to create a card token? If yes, how to avoid such messages?

**ANSWER:**

Yes, but it needs the highest level of permission, instead of **SAQ A** you need **SAQ D** verification.

Validation Process: https://stripe.com/docs/security#validating-pci-compliance
 (Select tab "**API Direct**")

**Summary:**

- Your transactions must be secure both physically, in code and fill all the requirements (encrypted card information over internet, keep your wifi connection secure, documentation if you are storing card data etc.)
- You need to fill out this PDF and upload to Stripe annually: https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/PCI-DSS-v3_2_1-SAQ-D_Merchant.pdf
- Your application should have PCI DSS Compliance and has to be filled in to the form above and be versioned: https://www.pcicomplianceguide.org/faq/
- If you got over 6 million transactions a year, you must fill out this PDF once a year: https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/PCI-DSS-v3_2_1-ROC-Reporting-Template.pdf
- As I understand this should also remove the message in the Stripe dashboard you are referring to.
- Stripe's Radar functionality will not work

**For reference, the API endpoint documentation:**

Create a token: https://stripe.com/docs/api/tokens/create_card

Create a charge: https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/create

---

**QUESTION 2**:

Or I have to use Stripe elements and one of their scripts for this?

**ANSWER:**

No, you don't have to. Only if you want a faster solution with lower level of permissions and less struggle, you can use the pre built Stripe element scripts.

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:**

Using Stripe.js v2 (Not JAVA but Javascript) to collect card information yourself and create a token, SAQ A-EP is required which needs a lower level of permission then the API which has SAQ D. See: https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/PCI-DSS-v3_2_1-SAQ-A_EP.pdf

But using Stripe.js v2 without Element is deprecated: https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/v2

[image: Stripe.js v2 deprecation]

So I do not know if this will remove the security warning in dashboard and the functionality could be removed later. **So the safest way to go if you require to handle Card Information yourself is getting the SAQ D verification and fill out the forms annually.** (For a website shop this should not be necessary and you should go with Elements, but for custom hardware integrations like Terminals, NFC scanners etc, this could be the simplest / only way to go if you have to integrate yourself).